# Admob dp, px screen: Admob is not coming to some devices only

Tags: android, admob, pixel

I have Ad in my applications. Ad is coming to several devices. but for others its not coming. I searched alot. I think, its because of the allotted space is not enough for Ads in high density devices.

I aloted

320 X 50 - for medium devices
468 X 75 - for large
780 X 90 - for extra large

Am not sure these values are in dp s ir

Answer (score 1):

Use the standerd admob size for both mobile and tablet. **AdSize.BANNER**.

Comment: yes. Thanks. I have galaxy 7 " tab for testing. When I added 468 X 60 Ad that show like it needs 485 X 75 i corrected the Size and added, its coming now. But if am using the banner size Ads in medium size devices, then how will the width match? 320 X 50 is the banner size. usual medium device size is 320 in width. So Ad width is not matching. it seems like Ad needs much space thats why its not coming. So is there any small Ads than this Banner? Thanks